# Launching app by swiping from corner

Tags: android, xamarin, swipe

So what I wanna do is make app that will display information and allow you to launch other apps from that main screen but I want that screen to appear when I swipe from corner (right bottom ..) from any app and any screen like swipe pad app or swipe drawer type of apps.. Any ideas? :)

Comment: I'm assuming you'll have to draw something in the bottom corner, and respond to touch events on it

Comment: Hmm yes that might work but I`m not sure how to do it but you give my interesting idea.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by service.
this will make your button show on top of everything so you can hide it and show a small line or something or even a transparent icon and when user touches it it will do what ever you want.

Comment: Great that is exaclly what I want but I`m not able to find it online can you please give me link with example of that or provide code to to that?